# IgnoreQueryFilters does not ignore filters on a boolean

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I use global filters on Photos in the DbContext. Each photo has a property called isApproved, if the photo is not approved it should be equal to false.

So in method OnModelCreating, I set a global filter like this

```
builder.Entity<Photo>().HasQueryFilter(p => p.IsApproved);
```

And then it works as expected, returns everything which is true.
However, for the current user which is logged in, I want to be able the user to see the photos even though they are in an approval state. And I apply IgnoreFilter to the repository as such:

```
public async Task<User> GetUser(int id, bool isCurrentUser)
    {
        var query = _context.Users.Include(p => p.Photos).AsQueryable();

        if (isCurrentUser)
        {
            // For current user the global filter is dissabled
            query = query.IgnoreQueryFilters();
        }

        // When retrieve the user, we retrieve his photos as well.
        var user = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);

        // returning default means null if the user doesn`t matches his id
        return user;
    }
```

When I retrieve the user, I still cannot see the not approved w photos even though I ignore the rule for the signed-in user. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is, because you are simply not doing anything with your `query`, but instead, define a second `user` object, that is ignoring your `query`. The consequence is, that the user variable, is executing a query against your data-store with global filters enabled.

In short: You have to execute your query and return it. There is no need for a seperate user object. So either you simply change the `user` object to: `var user = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);` or, when you want to do it a bit more concise and shorter:

```
public async Task<User> GetUser(int id, bool isCurrentUser)
{
    var query = _context.Users.Include(p => p.Photos).AsQueryable();

    if (isCurrentUser)
    {
        // For current user the global filter is dissabled
        query = query.IgnoreQueryFilters();
    }

    return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);
}
```